# Java Question about Setting a Word as a Variable

Tags: java

I am making a rock paper scissors program. I want the user of the program to enter either rock, paper, or scissors (hence the imported scanner) and I want the computer to choose a random number (I will import a java.util.Random) that corresponds to another rock, paper, or scissor.

So I am trying to make the program RECOGNIZE a word as something significant. That is to say, if the user inputs "rock" in the scanner, the computer will do some output. In the below code, I tried to get the computer to output "yes" if the user inputs "rock". To do this, I set a variable called "player" to be the inputted text, and a String rock to be the phrase "rock". I then said that if player=rock(="rock"), then we will get "yes".

There were no errors in the program. But when I inputted "rock" into the scanner, the program did nothing. What did I do wrong and how can I correct it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Refined {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String rock = "rock";

        String player;
        System.out.println("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");
        player = abc.next();
        if(player == rock){
            System.out.println("yes");

        }
    }
```

Comment: There are soo many duplicates... search for "java string equals"

Answer (score 1):

Use `player.equals(rock)` or `player.equalsIgnoreCase(rock)` to compare contents of both variables

If we apply `==` to compare two string objects it compares the `references` of both the objects so in your case references are difference that is  why it is returning false and `System.out.println("yes");` is not being printed.

Use `String.equals()` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` method to compare contents of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You want `player.equals(rock)` in the `if` condition.

Putting `player == rock` compares the `String` objects (basically whether the references in memory point at the same spot), not the value actually stored in the `String` objects.

Answer (score 0):

player and rock are String objects. In Java we dont have String as a datatype, like int, float, etc. So to compare two objects we must use .equals() [ which comes from the Object class ]